# SmartNews風タブUIのおすすめのパッケージ

Tags: swift, ios, swift5

今、SmartNews(スマートニュース)風のアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、
どのパッケージもSwift5に対応しているものがありません。

なにかおすすめのものがありましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

調べたパッケージ

- [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)
- [PageMenuKitSwift](https://github.com/magickworx/PageMenuKitSwift)
- [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu/tree/master/Classes)
- [PagingMenuController](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)のGitHubリポジトリのREADMEには、Swift5に対応する旨表記されていますので、これが使えるはずです。

もしくはそのようなUIの作り方を解説した[記事](https://medium.com/@erthru/implement-android-like-sliding-tabs-in-swift-xcode-13061f5444fc)を参考に、自作してみてもよいと思います（単純なものであれば数百行程度で実装できるみたいです）。

Comment: とても参考になりました。ありがとうございます。